# "No child processes" on os.waitpid

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu

I'm trying to simulate behavior of `os.system` with `Popen` and `waitpid` on Ubuntu and I'm getting

```
OSError: [Errno 10] No child processes
```

here's how I'm using it

```
p = Popen(args, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
returncode = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

I tried to get return code out of `p.returncode` , but it is always `None`, any ideas how to get the return code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`communicate` already waits on the child process to terminate, and collects the return code itself. Therefore, when you call `os.waitpid`, you're calling it referencing a process ID that has already been removed from the OS tables. Therefore, you get the "No child process" error.

The return code you're looking for will be stored in the [returncode](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) field of of the process object after `communicate` returns.

Comment: Good point, it's in p.returncode, I thought it was None by looking at the wrong printout

Answer (score 2):

Use [`p.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) or [`p.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait).

Comment: The OP is mixing calls to incompatible parts of the library. If you open the process with Popen(), use the object's wait() routine to get its exit code, not os.waitpid.

Comment: @MarkR: Thanks for elaborating. I was going for 'documentation hipster read the docs before it was cool,' so I couldn't in the actual answer ;)

Comment: PS That is a glorious avatar.

Comment: @MarkR, I got the idea for waitpid here -- http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

Comment: I don't think this answer will actually get you where you want to be. If all you're looking for is the return code after you call `communicate`, then see the answer I posted.

Comment: @tylerl: The OP mentions that `returncode` doesn't work for them. `poll()` is exactly what's needed.

Comment: @Yaroslav: Note that that example *doesn't* use `communicate` in between the `Popen` and the `os.waitpid`.